# specifying uirequireddevicecapabilties of iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12

Tags: ios, xcode

So - I'm trying to add the device capability requirement

```
iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12
```

which seems to map to exactly the capabilities I actually need, which is "supports avcapturemulticamsession"

but I just get this error when trying to validate:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
This bundle is invalid. The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '13.5'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so... according to apple support that iphone-ipad-minimum-performance-a12 is ios 14 only.

Comment: Thank you, lifesaver! That stuff is really hard to google somehow.